# All columns rounding up except new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add this column to an already existing dataframe.

```
df['THRESHOLD'] = df['AVG_CNT'] * 3
cols = ['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']
df[cols] = df[cols].round(1)
print (df)
```

I want to round the columns to a single significant figure. All the columns get rounded up except the new `df['THRESHOLD']` column. Why is this so?

Results of df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 16 entries, 0 to 15
Data columns (total 4 columns):
AVG_CNT      16 non-null float64
ID           16 non-null int64
STD_DEV      16 non-null float64
THRESHOLD    16 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1)
memory usage: 640.0 bytes
None
```

Comment: can you share `df.info()`?

Comment: @RichieV I just added it

Comment: did you do a df.head() to see if it has rounded. I dont see anything wrong with your code

Comment: @JoeFerndz ah... weirdly, it rounds up when i use `df.head`, but doesn't round up when i try to print everything with `df`

Comment: if you want to just display single decimal, you can just do this `pd.options.display.precision = 1` and all your displays will be single digit

Comment: Not sure why you are getting the issue. i tried to do df and i am getting the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round` to do this.

You can do it in a few ways.

```
df = df.round({'AVG_CNT': 1, 'STD_DEV': 1, 'THRESHOLD': 1})
```

or like you did:

```
cols = ['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']
df[cols] = df[cols].round(1)
```

or

```
df[['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']] = df[['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']].round(1)
```

or use `apply` and `Series.round`

```
df[['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']] = df[['AVG_CNT', 'STD_DEV', 'THRESHOLD']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x, 1))
```

or

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x, 1))
```